# Debugging from PyCharm to Visual Studio C++ code

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, debugging, pycharm

I'm currently trying to debug issues in [Caffe for Windows](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) PyCaffe.

Because of a [bug in Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/1439), PTVS doesn't work so I'm using PyCharm and trying to attach to PyCaffe's process through Visual Studio 2013.  That is, I'm running PyCharm debugger on a Python script with a breakpoint set at the point where I call the Python entry point into PyCaffe.

I debug the Python script in PyCharm which calls modules written in C++ in VS.  I want to debug those modules in C++.  So I'm trying to attach to the PyCharm or Python processes with breakpoints set in VS.

The problem is that the breakpoint isn't firing at the entry point in PyCaffe in the Visual Studio C++ code.

Has anyone successfully gotten this kind of thing to work or is there an alternative way of doing this?

Comment: Pycharm is an IDE, how are you attaching through VS 2013? That just sounds confusing. Are you debugging c++ code or python code? It really isn't clear.

Comment: @limbo I debug the Python script in PyCharm which calls modules written in C++ in VS.  I want to debug those modules in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem a few years ago, trying to
debug a user-mode driver wish was loading automatically from a RPC, the solution I found was:

1. Download Debugging Tool for Windows (depending on your system x86 or x64), wish is free,from the Microsoft Download.
2. Add "__asm int 3"(this is asm instruction for a hardware breakpoint) in the place on the C code where you whant to the break point to take effect.
3. Compile the C program, nomally with debug info (this part is important,because help the Debugger to find the source file), this should not make any problems.
4. Attach the Debugger to the running process (in my case was the explorer process), in your case should be the process that make first call to the library, for example if PyCharm create a process for the new python code, the debugger need to be attached to that process(you can manage this by setting a breakpoint in python, wish will give you time for doing the attach process), the easy way for me to figure this out was to let the process crash, because "__asm int 3" cause a process crash if a debugger is not attach, you can take advantage of this waiting for the crash and when windows shows you the screen "Process ... has detected a problem an need to be closed", you know who is the process that you are looking for.

This could be painful the first time but for me quite effective, because you
can see the data flow from one program to another,

Answer (score 0):

We attach to one process and allow to set breakpoints within code that has not started from the VS debugger. But one important issue is that we often debug/run the app in the VS, for example, we debug the Web code that runs under IIS, we will attach to the IIS process or others.

Your project is different from the above sample, you run/debug your app in Pycharm (not the VS), but you want use the VS Attach to process function, so it would have a limitation. As you said that you debug script in PyCharm, and want to call C++, so you would check that whether the PyCharm supports a similar feature like the attach tool in VS.